# Git: Moving a branch that was based on another to be based on master

Tags: git, github, branch, rebase

The instructors for one of my classes have opted to create a single repository with folders for each assignment of the class I'm in now. This isn't my first brush with git or github for that matter, but this setup is very prone to confusion.

Each assignment is worked on as a branch, and to "submit" it as our final version we create a pull request back to master. That much is easy. But I've just begun to work on a new project, and in creating its branch, I've seemingly included all the commits for the prior project, such that my repo looks like this:

```
  { Project A Commits } { Pr. B Commits }
  --o--o--o--o---o----o------------o----o ProjectB
 /
o---------------------------------------- master
 \
  --o--o--o--o---o----o ProjectA
```

When it really ought to look like this:

```
  ----o----o ProjectB
 /
o---------------------------------------- master
 \
  --o--o--o--o---o----o ProjectA
```

I know that there's such a thing as `rebase`, but that seems to apply to slightly different scenarios than the pickle I've gotten myself into. I really don't want all of the changes from ProjectA piling up in ProjectB while I await ProjectA's pull request to be approved by the instructors.

Comment: you can do this visually using Source Tree, rebase children of [root commit] interactively... this will give you a list of commits on your ProjectB branch and you can delete any commits on the branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to rewrite history so that the parent of the first B commit is the root.

That's what `git rebase`, and specifically `git rebase -i`, is for.

Check out branch B, run `git rebase -i <ID of root commit>`, then delete all of the commits you want to remove.

Comment: I tried that just now, and removed other commits that didn't belong to the work I did on Project B, but after the rebase, ProjectB's branch was still full of Project A commits.

Comment: That should not happen.  What was the output from the rebase? What's `git log` before and after?

Comment: So what's happening is the extraneous commits showing up in the interactive rebase mode are all from a project prior to A, when I remove them all the project A stuff is still in ProjectB branch. The rebase runs successfully with no errors, and the logs/rebase file are as follows:  http://phrz.io/dR9N (Log: Before), http://phrz.io/dQh7 (Log: After), http://phrz.io/dQs3 (Rebase list: Before), http://phrz.io/dQbA (Rebase list: After)

Comment: @phrz: Pass a commit ID from before the commits you want to remove, then remove all of the commits (including project A).  Rebasing has nothing to do with other branches; it just lets you remove all the commit(s) you don't want.

Comment: Will I lose those commits, though? I still need the commits pertaining to Project A the prior ones, I just don't want them on that branch, which is where it appears they are

Comment: @phrz: No; `git rebase` just affects the current branch (creating new commits).  It is impossible to directly "destroy" a commit in git; however, commits that are not referenced by any branch or tag will eventually be removed by `git gc`.